# Submit a form in the background

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How can I submit a form to a third-party website without it causing the page to reload (i.e. in the background)?

For some background, I'm trying to programmatically log a user into their google account in the background.

I can programmatically log them in using the following:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = FORM_HTML;
var form = div.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
form.action = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth";
form.GALX.value = FORM_GALX; // dynamically obtained using AJAX
form.Email.value = USER_EMAIL;
form.Passwd.value = USER_PASSWORD;
form.submit();
```

This logs me in and opens up my Google dashboard.  How can I prevent `form.action` from redirecting me?

Please note that this div is never actually added to a document, which is preferable but not required.

Comment: Tongue-in-cheek answer:  This can be done through a method known as cross-site scripting.    https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29  Yeah, I believe his intention is not malicious, but just the same.

Comment: @David — No, that's [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) not XSS

Comment: @Quentin - that's right.  Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure that this method wouldn't even work from a webpage (since google has CSRF protection to avoid malicious tracking); this is being run from a Chrome Extension (which means it isn't _technically_ CSRF).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can set the target to submit the form to an IFRAME
like that

```
<form target="transFrame" method="POST" action="http://...."  ></form>
<iframe style="" name="transFrame" id="transFrame"></iframe>
```

Comment: Actually I have a follow-up to this.  When I post to an iframe, how can I register when the server has responded?  onload="alert('load');" doesn't work and the iframe's contents never seem to change.

Comment: @alex c, I know how to do it in jQuery: `$('#transFrame').ready(function () {alert("loaded")});`

Comment: If the server is too slow, chrome will cancel the request if an existing form submit is already being processed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use AJAX to generate XMLHttpRequest best using any popular JS library such as jQuery, Prototype JS or Mootools.

Comment: Problem, its a cross site request

Comment: you can use an opaque fetch request to receive only basic data about a request. works cross-site.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax or jquery for request to submit form in background if you want to submit form to secure connection i think they want allow submit form in this way..